# VBA - Connect Excel 2007 Spreadsheet to Access 2007 Database via ADODB

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, ms-access

Currently there is a Excel 2002 spreadsheet writing/retrieving data from a Access 2002 database.  IT is presently researching a upgrade to Office 2007 and when I upgrade both the spreadsheet and database the ADODB connection fails.

The 2002 era VBA connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password = stackoverflow; 
Data Source= \\test\test.mdb"
```

In usage:

```
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
cnt.Open LiveCon
```

Changing the .mdb suffix to .accdb breaks the connection.  Can someone direct me to the new syntax for the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
```

to

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

Comment: After I upgraded the provider string a 'Could not find installable ISAM' error messsage appeared.  After some research it appears that the '2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components' may need to be installed.
The library can be found at:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

You may find this helpful: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Comment: Thanks - keep forgetting about that website.